# what does constant property means in swift?

Tags: swift

I am learning SWIFT. I don't understand one sentence while reading book. What does the sentence below means?:

> “Add a constant property called elementList to ViewController.swift
>   and initialize it with the following element names: let elementList =
>   ["Carbon", "Gold", "Chlorine", "Sodium"]”
>   does it mean create new class or I have to create struct?

Answer (score -1):

In you situation, you are creating an array of string and store it into a constant variable called `elementList`. When you use `let` to create this variable, it means that the value cannot be changed afterwords. So you cannot add or remove element after declaring this array in this way, etc

Answer (score -1):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var intValue = 1 //This is a property, but it is variable. That means its value can be changed in future.
    let doubleValue = 3.14 // This is a property too, but it is constant. That means its value can't be change
    // Both `intValue` & `doubleValue` will be in memory till ViewController's existence.

}
```

**IN YOUR CASE:**

```
let elementList = ["Carbon", "Gold", "Chlorine", "Sodium"]
```

`elementList` is a **array** of `String`, since `let` keyword denotes that it is a ***constant property***

> To Add a constant property called elementList to ViewController.swift and initialize it. **IT WOULD LOOK SOMETHING LIKE THIS**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let elementList = ["Carbon", "Gold", "Chlorine", "Sodium"]

    //..
}
```

Comment: I know it but why it is written elementList to ViewController.swift  ?

Comment: ViewController.swift would be a swift file contains ViewController class. I have added the answer to it too.